# I have a ton of dates (listed as characters in a column) on a .csv file. How do I convert them to dates without having to list all of them?

Tags: r, csv, date

I'm quite new to R, but I'm especially new to working with dates. I've got a .csv file with a column titled, "Date." Dates are listed as "9_12_22," etc., etc. I see that a lot of solutions use strings to work with dates, like:
strDates <- c("01/05/1965", "08/16/1975")
dates <- as.Date(strDates, "%m/%d/%Y")
And you use the lubridate functions to do so. This makes sense. But I have well over a hundred dates (big psych project) and I need to convert these dates seamlessly and automatically (I'm not going to write out a hundred-variable string!)
What's more is that I'd like to convert these dates to the standard R date format rather than the awkward underscore situation. There's not much I can do to change the .csv file (the output data is set in stone).

#Script example
Data_Dates <- read.csv("myfilename.csv")

I've tried using gsub to get rid of the underscores:
gsub("_", "/", Data_Dates, fixed=TRUE)

This did not work.

I've also tried manually reading in the dates:

```
Data_Dates <- read.csv("filename.csv") %>%
  select(Date) %>%
  mdy("01_14_2022","01_21_2022","02_03_2022","02_07_2022","02_09_2022","02_16_2022","02_17_2022","02_21_2022","02_24_2022","03_03_2022","03_16_2022","03_21_2022","03_23_2022","03_24_2022","03_25_2022","03_31_2022","04_04_2022","04_06_2022",etc.)
```

THIS TAKES FOREVER! I quit after a while because it seems futile.

Comment: have you tried `select(mdy(Date))` or `select(as.Date(Date, format = "%m_%d_%Y"))`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problems are confusions with syntax, not any issues with the dates.

Let's say your data frame has a column named `Date` with dates in the format `m_d_y`. Here's some sample data:

```
Data_Dates = data.frame(Date = 
  c("01_14_2022","01_21_2022","02_03_2022","02_07_2022","02_09_2022",
  "02_16_2022","02_17_2022","02_21_2022","02_24_2022","03_03_2022",
  "03_16_2022","03_21_2022","03_23_2022","03_24_2022","03_25_2022",
  "03_31_2022","04_04_2022","04_06_2022"
))
```

What you want to do is apply the `lubridate::mdy` function to that column. With `dplyr`, we use `mutate` to create new columns or edit existing columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

Data_Dates %>%
  mutate(Nice_Date = mdy(Date))
#          Date  Nice_Date
# 1  01_14_2022 2022-01-14
# 2  01_21_2022 2022-01-21
# 3  02_03_2022 2022-02-03
# 4  02_07_2022 2022-02-07
# 5  02_09_2022 2022-02-09
# 6  02_16_2022 2022-02-16
# 7  02_17_2022 2022-02-17
# 8  02_21_2022 2022-02-21
# 9  02_24_2022 2022-02-24
# 10 03_03_2022 2022-03-03
# 11 03_16_2022 2022-03-16
# 12 03_21_2022 2022-03-21
# 13 03_23_2022 2022-03-23
# 14 03_24_2022 2022-03-24
# 15 03_25_2022 2022-03-25
# 16 03_31_2022 2022-03-31
# 17 04_04_2022 2022-04-04
# 18 04_06_2022 2022-04-06
```

This works fine and very quickly.

Do note that I did not assign the result with `<-` or `=`, so the result prints but is not saved. If you want to assign the result to a new object, give it a name, e.g., `Nice_Data_Dates <- Data_Dates %>% mutate...`, or you can assign it to the same name to modify the existing object, `Data_Dates <- Data_Dates %>% mutate...`.

Probably you do **not** want to `select()` the `Date` column, as that will select **only the date column** and drop the other columns. Probably you want to `mutate` the date column in place, as I have here.